# Azure Stream Analytics - How to save data for more than one IoT device in Azure SQL db

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am able to save data for one running IoT device in Azure SQL DB but not able to understand how to save data in Azure SQL DB for data coming from more than 1 IoT device using stream analytics, the data can be different.
For example -
Device1 may produce temperature, humidity
and Device2 may produce torque, pressure

I have used the [stream analytics preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sd5o.jpg) feature in Azure SQL DB. I didn't want to create a schema for the table because I'm not sure what kind of data will be coming from different IoT devices.

Comment: I understand from your question that each device is emitting data points with different schemas? Have you thought about the schema that you want to use in your destination? By that I mean what columns and their data types? Do you expect to have columns like temperature, humidity, torque, pressure, that will always be half empty (depending on the source device), or do you want instead to get to 2 columns like sensorName, sensorValue? Depending on how you want to store the data, I can help you write the proper query

Comment: Yes, multiple devices emitting data points with different schemas, that's what I'm assuming at the point.

For your second question, no, as the coming data would be heterogenous haven't thought about the schema of the output necessarily. I just wanted to see how I can store data coming of multiple IoT devices in a relational table in azure.

the sensorName and sensorValue seem like a good idea for my use case, can you link me a good article for this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to proceed here is the following one:

```
WITH 
TempInput AS (SELECT DeviceId, 'Temperature' AS sensorName, Temperature AS sensorValue FROM Input WHERE DeviceType = 'A'),

HumidityInput AS  (SELECT DeviceId, 'Humidity' AS sensorName, Humidity AS sensorValue FROM Input WHERE DeviceType = 'A'),

TorqueInput AS (SELECT DeviceId, 'Torque' AS sensorName, Torque AS sensorValue FROM Input WHERE DeviceType = 'B'),

PressureInput AS  (SELECT DeviceId, 'Pressure' AS sensorName, Pressure AS sensorValue FROM Input WHERE DeviceType = 'B')

UnionOutput AS (
SELECT DeviceId, sensorName, sensorValue FROM TempInput 
UNION
SELECT DeviceId, sensorName, sensorValue FROM HumidityInput
UNION
SELECT DeviceId, sensorName, sensorValue FROM TorqueInput 
UNION
SELECT DeviceId, sensorName, sensorValue FROM PressureInput
)

SELECT *
INTO Output
FROM UnionOutput
```

So this scenario is supported, but the query pattern above can't really be generalized until we know more about the actual schemas involved. We have smarter ways to parse and pivot data that may be applicable in your specific case. It's important to have more details both in terms of input (CSV, JSON, how are fields nested or not, arrays) and output. We have a [good doc on general patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns), but also [parsing JSON data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json) that can help.